# LMDB: change label of entry in already made lmdb file

Tags: caffe, lmdb

I have a large (> 1TB) lmdb file made for caffe. It took a long time to generate. Now I want to change the labels of some of the entries. Is there a way to change the label in place? There is a work around that I could delete them and add them back. But this will lead to all the changed labels (a new class in my case) being at the end of lmdb file, which I think is not good for training.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution after some search. I can use replace function, as mentioned in https://lmdb.readthedocs.io/en/release/.

Here is the code snippet for the solution:

```
map_size = N
env = lmdb.open(lmdb_name, map_size=map_size) 
with env.begin(write=True) as txn: 
    cursor = txn.cursor() 
    for key, value in cursor: 
        datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum() 
        datum.ParseFromString(value)
        datum_new = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
        datum_new.channels = 3
        datum_new.height = size
        datum_new.width = size
        datum_new.data = datum.data
        datum_new.label = 13
        cursor.replace(key, datum_new.SerializePartialToString())
```

Comment: @DmytroPrylipko Yes, of course. This is the code I use. `map_size = N
env = lmdb.open(lmdb_name, map_size=map_size)
with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
    cursor = txn.cursor()
    for key, value in cursor:
          datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
          datum.ParseFromString(value)
          datum_new = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
          datum_new.channels = 3
          datum_new.height = size
          datum_new.width = size
          datum_new.data = datum.data
          datum_new.label = 13
          cursor.replace(key, datum_new.SerializePartialToString())`